# iPhone Private distribution

Tags: iphone, app-store, distribution

I am new to iPhone world. 
I have developed an application, which I would like to send to all the iphones come under the vicinity of a particular wi-fi access point. (It is meant for a shopping mall)

With my limited knowledge in this, I understand, I cannot distribute the application through my webserver. I even cant use the 'Ad hoc mode' suggested by Apple, as registering of all the mobile phones is impractical.

I would like to know whether the only solution is 'distribution through appstore'? Or any other solution available?

Expecting your help.

Thanks.

Comment: An application that automatically install as I walk down the food court and then start spamming me with mall advertised products? I'm so glad this is impossible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible solution is to make a web app instead of a native app.

Comment: this is a much better idea -- and one less likely to run afoul of Apple's abitrary appstore limits.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean that the application would automatically be loaded onto phones when they move into a certain shopping mall, then yes, I can see that you are new to iPhone development! :)

For security reasons, the user has to specifically choose to download the app.

If the app is not iPhone-specific but simply a web page made up to look like an app, then you could use SMS to send a URL to the phone. But that would require you to know the phone number, which is also not made available through any kind of local wireless communication, again for obvious security reasons.

The simplest approach would be to put a poster up in the mall, telling iPhone users that they can find the mall's app on the iTunes App Store.

Comment: Thanks a lot Earwicker for your quick response. 

I understand, the automatic download is impossible, and probably would go for an announcement or a poster as you mentioned. 

So the only, option in front of me is Appstore. 
Now I have another doubt in this regard. 

Wouldnt the app uploaded to appstore be downloadable for public, evenif they are not from my shop? 
So, is there any option to restrict the download, (Like providing a download password)

Also I would like to confirm, whether these sort of 'private applications uploaded to app store' are common?

Once again thanking you..

Comment: Downloading an app does not imply running it. Obviously you can make the app ask for a password when it starts up. If you're talking about an app that stores/reveals the user's private, personal data, then yes, you definitely need username/password protection. Restricting the download wouldn't help at all. If the app doesn't store personal data, then why do you need to restrict access to it at all? Most stores want potential customers to see their advertising, regardless of physical location!

Comment: Thaks .. that really makes sense.. Now what I understand from your replies is,
1) I need to upload the application to appstore, with 'access to all' 
2) User will be directed to download and "run" this
3) A password protection may be incorporated (if found needed)
..
Please correct if I am wrong !